# TypeError when creating a new user

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

After following [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) tutorial to create a signup view, I have encountered an error.

Here is the view:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.is_active = False
            new_user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = "Activate your DC-Elects account"
            message = render_to_string('registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': new_user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(used.id)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            new_user.email_user(subject, message)
            return reverse('elections:account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html',{
        'form': form,
    })
```

Here is the extended user model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    UserID = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    GENDERS = (("M","Male"), ("F","Female"))
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS)
    UserTypeID = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    ProfilePicture = models.ImageField(default='default_profile.png', upload_to="imageposts/")
    EmailConfirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # For student number, can you have choices - Teacher or input()?

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Everything goes fine when filling out the form as the user, but when I submit the form, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cbuch1800\Coursework\mysite\elections\views.py", line 325, in signup
    new_user.save()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 848, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\cbuch1800\Coursework\mysite\elections\models.py", line 25, in create_user_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 573, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I'm not sure where or why the error is being raised, since a new user is still being created and saved to the database, I am just getting this error instead of the email being sent.

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have field `UserID` in Profile model, so you need to use it in create method instead of `user`:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(UserID=instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Your `Profile` model definition does not contain any field named `user`.